# Rewriting url rewrite rule tio IIS 7

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, web-config

I hope you can help me guys, here is my problem, i need to configure this URL Rewrite .httacces rule to a web.config file, because the site will run on IIS 7 and is developed in php

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule    ^web/contacto.php$    contacto/  [R,L]
RewriteRule    ^web/marcas.php$    marcas/  [R,L]
RewriteRule    ^web/categoria.php$ busqueda/resultados/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIS Manager allows you to import htaccess rules and converts them for you...

Answer (score 0):

IIS Manager allows you to import htaccess rules and converts them for you...